# Review Audit: How *deep* should I be thinking?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I'm somewhat new to the queue, have passed all my audits up to today, where I just had my first [review audit failure](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/27035105). At first glance it seems like "woah, you weren't paying attention" but let me explain my logic:

When this answer comes up for "review", it's presented as a one-line answer, four hours old with a default-avatar username like "user2390983590" or some such string, which throws up flags for me in general. So I go to open the actual question thread, where I see that up-voted, word-for-word answer already posted by a different user three weeks ago.

So in my head, all I see is someone trying to sneak through duplicate answers in search of rep or answer count. Since Spam is defined as "Exists only to promote a product or service, does not disclose the author's affiliation", I instead flagged for Moderator intervention and described that it was a copy-paste of a previous answer.

Well that was wrong. No intervention required apparently, which I feel like I would have recognized if the audit had just shown me the actual author information outright. The only reason I went to the thread itself was because of that suspicious info but even still, I would have seen that it was an existing, up-voted answer and realized this was an audit.

So I guess my question is am I overthinking the review process entirely? Should I be treating each post in the queue truly at face value and not consider it in the context of the thread as a whole? Or is this just a trap I have to look out for? Even then, how do I differentiate between that kind of audit and a situation like I had assumed, where legitimate answers are being duplicated by new users?

I take this seriously so I want to know how the experienced reviewers are handling it.

Comment: It is a "trap" in the sense that it tries to weed-out users that don't look at the Q+A.  The biggest problem with review and what forced the audit feature to get added, SO users get pretty batty when their valid flags get dismissed by inattentive reviewers.  You did look, so you did it right and can never fail that audit.

Comment: @HansPassant I totally understand the reason for them and 100% think it's the right thing to have. This particular audit felt like a "trap" to me but maybe that's not the best word to use. I guess I'm just surprised that I could fail it by overthinking. Also, hello from Milwaukee!

Comment: You did the right thing by opening up the post and looking at the whole picture. There is a trick to finding out which exact post you're really looking at. Open it up from the link on the right sidebar :)

Comment: FYI, you did the right thing. Just ignore such audits, and don't make the same mistake as me :D. Whenever you are reviewing, looking for extra context is always the best thing to do.

Comment: Weren't you surprised that the answer by the new user which you were looking for wasn't there on the original question? Or haven't you checked that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed first post review audit because of tricky layout/user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269124/failed-first-post-review-audit-because-of-tricky-layout-user), also [High quality audit shows what appears to be a plagiarized answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266379/high-quality-audit-shows-what-appears-to-be-a-plagiarized-answer)

Comment: @Nick "posts in the review queues are posted before reviewing, not after" I think that's the root of it right there, thanks

Comment: @Tom if you read my post you'd know i did. what i didn't know was they post before, not after queue. but thanks for your contribution.

Comment: @parttimeturtle Yeah, these audits can be a bit funny if you're not expecting them as they do appear to be duplicate answers (especially due to the name and score changes shown on the audit screen). The good news is, now you know they exist you won't fall for another one right? ;)

Comment: @parttimeturtle I read you post and you didn't mention it, so saying " if you read my post you'd know i did." is rather misleading. You said you found an answer by someone else and thought the reviewed post must be a duplicate, but you apparently didn't check if the reviewed post by user2390983590 is in the list of answers as well, that is why I asked. You just assumed it must be a duplicate without properly checking that.

Comment: Very, very deep. Audits are the worst - some of them rely on outside info, especially for answers deleted as spam when they aren't even remotely obvious. Samuel Liew has a userscript that skips audits - I don't remember where it is atm, but the point  being that your best option here is to not play

Comment: @Zoe Once you know how the audits work and are able to spot them, they're very easily done. Some of us like "playing" with them.